# jquery: Toggle elements based on result from a function

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a number of table rows that I would like to toggle the visibility of. They should be visible if a data item I have set on them earlier equals a selected value in a form. This is what I have so far:

```
$('#category-selector').change(function(event)
{
    var category_id = $(this).val();

    if(!category_id)
    {
        $('tr', '#table tbody').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('tr', '#table tbody').toggle();
    }
});
```

Of course this just toggles them on and off. Thing is that I thought I was able to give `toggle` a function that would decide if each row should be on or off, but it turns out I can only give it a boolean condition which would be an all or nothing deal kind of...

So, I have this function:

```
function()
{
    return $(this).data('category_id') == category_id;
}
```

How can I use that to go through all the rows and toggle them on or off? Or is there a better approach to this? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still curious if there are better or smoother or faster ways of doing this, but this is how I have done it now:

```
else
{
     $('tr', '#table tbody').each(function()
     {
         $(this).toggle(  $(this).data('category_id') == category_id  );
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#category-selector').change(function(event)
{
    var category_id = $(this).val();

    $('tr', '#table tbody').toggle($(this).data('category_id') == category_id);
});
```

Comment: but will that be evaluated for each row? Isn't $(this) the category select tag here?

Comment: I don't know what #category-selector is. Try it and see?

Comment: `$('#category-selector')` is a `<select>` element.